# Filtering "All" category by props with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I'm having a filter logic on the page. Clicking on different buttons I'm filtering the initial array. How can I display all the items in the array to the sibling component by clicking the "All" button in the filtering component. Need to pass function to the parent component if I'm getting it right.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moon-djocul?file=/src/components/Filters.js.

```js
-----
Parent component
-----

const ShopPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(Categories);

  const filterResult = (catItem) => {
    if (!catItem) {
      console.log(Categories);
      setData(Categories);
    } else {
      const result = Categories.filter(
        (curData) => curData.category === catItem
      );
      setData(result);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <Filters filterResult={filterResult} />
        <Products products={data} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShopPage;


-----
Child component
-----

const Filters = ({ filterResult }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.filterbtns}>
        <div onClick={() => filterResult("Cap")} className={styles.filterbtn}>
          Cap
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => filterResult("Shirt")} className={styles.filterbtn}>
          Shirt
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={() => filterResult("Jogging")}
          className={styles.filterbtn}
        >
          Jogging
        </div>
        
        // needed to change the useState data of the compnonent and show all of the items
        <div onClick={() => filterResult()} className={styles.filterbtn}>
          All
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Filters;
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing `null` as `filterResult` parameter from the `all` button:

```
<div onClick={() => filterResult(null)} className={styles.filterbtn}>
    All
</div>
```

This can be captured in the `filterResult` function where you set the `result` back to the original `Categories` if no filter `category` was passed:

```
const result = catItem
      ? Categories.filter((curData) => curData.category === catItem)
      : Categories;
```

---

Updated SandBox:

[image: Edit jovial-microservice-0givb8]